# Get all documents with GridFSOperations

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, gridfs

I've decided to move one of our projects from PostgreSQL to MongoDB and this project deals with images. I am able to save images and retrieve them by their _id now but I couldn't find a function with GridFSOperations where I could safely get all documents. I am doing this so that I could take photo meta-data I saved with the image and index them with Lucene (as I needed a full text search on some relevant metadata, also future possible scenarios where we might need to rebuild the Lucene index)

In the old code, I simply had a function with an offset and limit for the SQL query as I found out (the hard way) that our dev system can only do bulk Lucene adds in groups of 5k. Is there an equivalent way of doing this with GridFS?

Edit:

function inherited from the old interface:

```
public List<Photo> getPublicPhotosForReindexing(long offset, long limit) {
    List<Photo> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<GridFSDBFile> files = gridFsOperations.find(new Query().limit((int) limit).skip((int) offset));
    for(GridFSDBFile file:files) {
        result.add(convertToPhoto(file));
    }
    return result;
}
```

a simple converter taking parts of the metadata and putting it in the POJO I made:

```
private Photo convertToPhoto(GridFSDBFile fsFile) {
    Photo resultPhoto = new Photo(fsFile.getId().toString());
    try {
        resultPhoto
                .setOriginalFilename(fsFile.getFilename())
     //         .setPhotoData(IOUtils.toByteArray(fsFile.getInputStream()))
                .setDateAdded(fsFile.getUploadDate());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Should not hit this one", e);
    }
    return resultPhoto;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an evaluation. Do you have some code as an example of what you have tried so far? Your question would benefit if you could show what you have done.

Comment: Well I could get all of the images with GridFSOperation.find(null) but I'm worried this will fail after around 100k images in the long run, perhaps even less with our system resources.
Let me just add in the basic code I did to try getting all of the docs.

Edit: Inserted simple code for getting all of the documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using GridFS the information is stored in your MongoDB database in two collections. The first is `fs.files` which has the main reference to the file and `fs.chunks` that actually holds the "chunks" of data. See the examples

Collection: **fs.files**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53229d20f3dde871df8b89a7"),
    "filename" : "receptor.jpg",
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-03-14T06:09:36.462Z"),
    "md5" : "f1e71af6d0ba9c517280f33b4cbab3f9",
    "length" : 138905
}
```

Collection: **fs.chunks**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53229d20824b12efe88cc1f2"),
    "files_id" : ObjectId("53229d20f3dde871df8b89a7"),
    "n" : 0,
    "data" : // all of the binary data

}
```

So really these are just normal MongoDB documents and normal collections.

As you can see, there are various ways you can "query" these collections with the standard API:

- The Object Id is monotonic and therefore ever increasing. Newer entries will have a higher ObjectId value than older ones. Most importantly, the last Id that was indexed.
- The `updloadDate` also holds a general date timestamp that you can use for date range based queries.

So you see, that GridFS is really just "Driver level magic" to work with ordinary MongoDB documents, and treat the binary data as a single document.

As they are just normal collections with normal documents, unless you are retrieving or otherwise updating the content, then just use the normal methods to select and find.

Comment: I tried adding a query to the null for the limit and skip which I found by browsing the docs (I should've done this earlier I guess) but I'm still getting all 7-8 documents instead of just 2 in the limit I passed.

Will .limit and .skip work only if there is an actual Criteria being thrown with them?

Comment: @CidImmacula The point is that you do not **have to** use the GridFS methods just to access the data. With a standard `.find()` and all of the query and cursor options you have there, then the data is just in standard collections. That allows you to *select* what you need. Your driver implementation "may" support all of this through it's GridFS functions, but if it does not, then you do not need it other than to read/write/delete the contents of the file.